# How to remove the white-bar which remains after typing in Android

Tags: android

For some reason, after a user enters text into an EditText within my Android app the white-bar which contains "suggestions" remains at the bottom of my Layout! If you press the "Back" button, it disappears.

How can I stop this from remaining after completing text entry?

EDIT:

Screenshots

Editing the text, white bar appears with suggestions:

[image]

And after going back to the ListView activity

[image]

Comment: Are you using the AutoCompleteTextView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html or a standard EditText?

Comment: It's just a standard EditText

Comment: You might consider posting a pair of screenshots, one during editing and one "after completing text entry" that shows the effect you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's kinda wild. I haven't seen that behavior before, on emulators or devices.

Unless you're planning on supporting Japanese or Chinese, turn off those IMEs in your emulator (Settings > Language & keyboard), and see if that changes your results.

Comment: I was a little confused as to why it was coming up with Japanese/Chinese suggestions ;) I'll try that. Should have some english hardware to test on next week so no worries! That fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What IME are you using?  The suggestion bar is part of the IME, the app doesn't have control over it.  This looks like a buggy IME.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problems running emulator with adnroid 2.1-update 1 only

---

well found solution: Just press one or two times escape on your keyboard
that will make it disappear